# Add a throws declaration to an overridden method

Tags: java, android

To improve the Reliability of a software I should not throw a java "standard" Exception (NullPointerException).
Now I have this code:

```
public JsonElement serialize(ExerciseType ex, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

    if(sMuscleMap == null || sLanguageMap == null || sEquipmentMap == null) 
        throw new NullPointerException("At least one map in " + TAG + " has not been initialized");


    JsonObject mainObject = new JsonObject();
}
```

The method "serialize" overrides com.google.gson.JsonSerialize method.
I've created my ErrorException but I can't throw it because I have to add the throws declaretion to the signature of the method and I can't of course modify the "original" "serialize" method too. 
There is a trick to do it?

Comment: well you can return any arbitrary value such as null or something in serialize method and then can have a value check in a calling method..

Comment: Don't declare `throws` for a runtime exception, though you should document it with `@throws` in the Javadoc comment.

Comment: "The method `serialize` overrides ..." You forgot to put in the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

> I've created my ErrorException

`Error` and `Exception` are two distinct things.
You should be careful with the naming of the exception and the base class to use.
You should extend `Exception` rather than `Error` as `Error` means a serious problem.

> The method "serialize" overrides com.google.gson.JsonSerialize method
>
> There is a trick to do it?

You could favor the composition over the inheritancy by introducing
a composition class that wraps a `JSonSerializer` and delegate to it the processings.
But is it really valuable ?

And to go further, is it really valuable to override this method of `JSonSerializer` ?
Rising a `NullPointerException` when a mandatory field is missing is common enough.
 It is an alternative to rise `IllegalArgumentException`.

This way of doing prevents from rising `NullPointerException` without helpful message to the class client.

Why do you think that you should introduce a checked exception instead of `NullPointerException`?

If the field is mandatory, the client should simply change its way to call the method.
It should not able to recover the problem at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle you cannot add restrictions to an override that the supertype cannot recognize. Since illegal arguments are a programmer mistake, they should be indicated by a runtime exception, not a checked exception anyway. Thankfully there is already a standard runtime exception for illegal arguments, `IllegalArgumentException`. Use that. Document it in the method Javadoc comment for your override, but you can't make it part of the actual method signature.